# Do I have to unmount not-linux partitions?

Tags: wubi

I remember that in old linux **before closing system** I had to **manually unmount** other partitions(**ntfs/fat32**). Do I have to do that in Ubuntu or is it magically **umounted before shutdown** by the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all filesystems which reside in the `/etc/fstab` file, will be automatically unmounted before the system shuts down.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't, all mounted partitions are unmounted before shutdown.